# I am experiencing a 404 error in the console on my django project

Tags: javascript, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I click add to cart on my django ecommerce website, the items are not added to cart and in the console an error message appears:

> VM40:1 Uncaught (in promise) Syntax Error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON) and (POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/ 404 (Not Found)

I tried adding a CSRF token in my `views.py` and `checkout.html` files but the CSRF token is not even displayed.

Here is my `view.py` code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime
from .models import * 

def store(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        #Create empty cart for now for non-logged in user
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        #Create empty cart for now for non-logged in user
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        #Create empty cart for now for non-logged in user
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)

def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        total = float(data['form']['total'])
        order.transaction_id = transaction_id

        if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.complete = True
        order.save()

        if order.shipping == True:
            ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            state=data['shipping']['state'],
            zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
            )
    else:
        print('User is not logged in')

    return JsonResponse('Payment submitted..', safe=False)
```

checkout.html

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div id="user-info">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="shipping-info">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Shipping Information:</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Zip code..">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Continue">
                </form>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="box-element hidden" id="payment-info">
                <small>Paypal Options</small>
                <button id="make-payment">Make payment</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'cart' %}">&#x2190; Back to Cart</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                <hr>
                {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x{{item.quantity}}</p></div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <h5>Items:   {{order.get_cart_items}}</h5>
                <h5>Total:   ${{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'
        var total = '{{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}'

        if (shipping == 'False'){
            document.getElementById('shipping-info').innerHTML = ''
        }

        if (user != 'AnonymousUser'){
            document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
         }

        if (shipping == 'False' && user != 'AnonymousUser'){
            //Hide entire form if user is logged in and shipping is false
                document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add("hidden");
                //Show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
                document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
        }

        var form = document.getElementById('form')

        csrftoken = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        console.log('Newtoken' ,form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value)
        
        /dform.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('Form Submitted...')
            document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add("hidden");
            document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
        })

        document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
            submitFormData()
        })

        function submitFormData(){
            console.log('Payment button clicked')

            var userFormData = {
                'name':null,
                'email':null,
                'total':total,
            }

            var shippingInfo = {
                'address':null,
                'city':null,
                'state':null,
                'zipcode':null,
            }

            if (shipping != 'False'){
                shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
                shippingInfo.city = form.city.value
                shippingInfo.state = form.state.value
                shippingInfo.zipcode = form.zipcode.value
            }

            if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
                userFormData.name = form.name.value
                userFormData.email = form.email.value
            }

            console.log('Shipping Info:', shippingInfo)
            console.log('User Info:', userFormData)

            var url = "/process_order/"
            fetch(url, {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'applicaiton/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                }, 
                body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo}),
                
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                  console.log('Success:', data);
                  alert('Transaction completed');  
                  window.location.href = "{% url 'store' %}"

                })
        }
    </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You are most likely getting an HTML response (instead of a JSON) to your AJAX request, which is causing the error. And that HTML response is likely a 404 page, which means that your frontend is unable to find the file which would receive the items. When you take a look at the  Network tab of your browser's DevTools, what is the URL which was contacted when you clicked on the button to add items to the cart?